# RAM usage of project based on typescript, Angular, NestJS

Tags: angular, typescript, performance, nestjs

Before I worked as a Drupal developer(up to 2017) and I worked with big databases where the applications were wrapped into containers.
But in bad scenarios, it required 4Gb maybe later 8GB. I understand that the RAM is dynamic and the smart system uses it properly to work fast.
Now I am working as a NodeJS developer. I am confused about memory consumption. The project is not so huge. There 4 NestJS services and 2 Angular clients.
During development, it utilizes 12Gb. I have only 16GB. From time to time it crashes my system. I can not profile it well.
Small weird numbers. I tried to monitor one NestJS typescript service. The system is registered for 1,1GB usage, I made a snapshot with Chrome tools, and it showed only 100MB of usage. I think that 100MB is too much for such an application. I do not feel performance issues until it crashed.
Sorry, I do not know the real case of production. Help me to know the real state. I use old typescript version 4.3. When I run jest that tests a small NestJS module without any integrations like Mongo in memory, a RAM spike is registered about 1.1GB. It is too much. Now I understand why the Github actions process so long for 7 minutes.

Is this a common case?
Does my computer fit for the development of such cases?
Where can I find real NestJS benchmarks?
What should check first?

My system is.

```
Linux hp 5.4.0-144-generic #161-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 3 14:49:04 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz
MemTotal:       16286464 kB
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript uses RAM depending on what you code.

So use the latest versions of every dependency (better performances), avoid complex algorithms, and optimize your code.

That's all there is really. I am able to run a triple Nest JS server + a mongo image on a raspberry for 10k users without any issues.if you can't run your projects on your own computer, blame your code first, not the language !

Comment: Maybe typescript compiles node_modules in some way?

Comment: Yes it does, but compilation has caching, and it happens once at build time, not anymore after that